# Postgres initialize 00:00:00 timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I'm trying to initialize a timestamp field with the first value being

```
-- Hours, minutes, seconds, subseconds    
00:00:00.000
```

This statement produces the following result. Is there a way to exclude everything except the hours, minutes, and seconds?

```
select to_timestamp('00:00:00.000', 'HH24:MI:SS.MS');
    0001-01-01 00:00:00-05:50:36 BC
```

Comment: Are you using a `timestamp` or a `time`?  [The former includes the date](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: If you only want a time, then use `time` not `timestamp`